# Ambari server can not start

Tags: linux, postgresql, hadoop

I have completed [Ambari](http://ambari.apache.org/) setup in CentOS 6.5, and started Ambari server successfully. But when I run `netstat|grep Ambari` command, nothing is shown.

I can not access the Ambari server with my browser. Please give me a hand, many thanks.

Ambari server start status:

```
ps -ef|grep Ambari
root     31424     1 10 17:45 pts/0    00:00:27 /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -server -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/ambari-server/conf/krb5JAASLogin.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -cp /etc/ambari-server/conf:/usr/lib/ambari-server/*:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/ambari-server/* org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer
```

ambari-config-changes.log:

```
17:48:03,591  INFO [Thread-22] AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:462 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1bqon9k938saoxzky1njv|3d0c29a1, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1bqon9k938saoxzky1njv|3d0c29a1, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 50, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://localhost/ambari, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 5, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 120, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> select 0, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
17:48:03,676  INFO [Thread-22] JobStoreTX:861 - Freed 0 triggers from 'acquired' / 'blocked' state.
17:48:03,694  INFO [Thread-22] JobStoreTX:871 - Recovering 0 jobs that were in-progress at the time of the last shut-down.
17:48:03,694  INFO [Thread-22] JobStoreTX:884 - Recovery complete.
17:48:03,695  INFO [Thread-22] JobStoreTX:891 - Removed 0 'complete' triggers.
17:48:03,696  INFO [Thread-22] JobStoreTX:896 - Removed 0 stale fired job entries.
17:48:03,708  INFO [Thread-22] QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler ExecutionScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

Comment: What's the output of `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep java` ? When you say you can't connect with your browser, what URL are you trying to use?

Comment: [root@vm1 ~]# netstat -ltnp | grep java
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      31424/java
tcp        0      0 :::8440                     :::*                        LISTEN      31424/java
tcp        0      0 :::8441                     :::*                        LISTEN      31424/java

Comment: It's much better if you edit your question to add output like that (in `{}` indented blocks). It's nearly illegible as a comment. Leave a comment when you've made the edit though. Also, the second part, what URL are you trying to connect to?

Comment: When I tried to connect Ambari server with IP,it is working.Thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather ... unclear ... but at a guess, you're not connecting to the correct port.

Try:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```